# Node - exceljs: writing to file breaks fomulas in the file

Tags: node.js, excel, npm, excel-formula, exceljs

I have an excel (xlsx) file that contains random columns. Some of these columns have formulas mapped to the sum of some cells; for example:

```
=J8+F9-H9
```

In my case I have the following three columns:

```
F: number
H: number
J: =sum of previous row's F and H cell's values.
```

I aim to get external data and store them cell by cell in this workbook. For this I am using Node module [exceljs.](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs)

This is my code so far, I am harcoding values for now (which I will be getting from another file later on).

```
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var filename = 'Bank Synoptic Journal.xlsx'
workbook
.xlsx
.readFile(filename)
.then(function() {
   var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Bank Synoptic');

   var row = null;
   row = worksheet.getRow(8);
   row.getCell('J').value = Math.random();
   row.commit();

   for(var i=9; i<=305;i++) { //row 
      row = worksheet.getRow(i);
      row.getCell('F').value = Math.random();
      row.getCell('H').value = Math.random();
      row.commit();
  }
})
.then(function() {
   return workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filename + '_modified.xlsx');
})
.then(function() {
   console.log('Done!');
});
```

It prints the output into a new excel file. The problem I am facing is that for cells 'J' ie which contains the formulas; these cells are breaking with no consitency:

- Some cells keep formulas and do the calculations
- Others have no more formulas nor calculations done (have '0' instead of formula)
- Recalculations are not done automatically using this injection mechanism

**(Snapshots)**

[image: snapshot]

[image: with formula]

[image: no formula]

What I am missing or doing wrong that is leading to this error?

Comment: In the `for` loop where you set random values for columns `F` and `H` you don't explicit set the formula for the previous row/ column `J` formula. Were you expecting the formula to be pre-set in the workbook you loaded for rows 9 to 305? Guess you should check that first.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie the workbook that I am filling the rows for already has formulas set in. That doesn't work?

Comment: Just thought it was useful to eliminate that possibility from the trouble-shooting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials and errors I moved to [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and so built the script using Java.

I downloaded and included the following JARs in my project:

[image: jars-used]

It manipulates rows/columns and keeps the formulas intact. Once you open the modified excel file all you have to do is refresh (On Windows: ctrl + alt + f9) and it will recalculate.

Comment: I want to protect a cell in Excel at run time. Is it possible to do this in node.js @Shadesco